# Parse JSON data from WordPress Custom post types in flutter

Tags: android, json, wordpress, dart, flutter

I working with a mobile application using flutter. Here I want to access WordPress custom post type slider in the flutter. I tried to like this

```
 import 'dart:async';
 import 'dart:convert';

 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

 void main() async {
   List _jsonData = await getJson();
   print(_jsonData);
       runApp(new MaterialApp(
          home: new Scaffold(
           appBar: new AppBar(
           title: new Text('Demo'),
           centerTitle: true,
           backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        ),
         body: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
              new Text(_jsonData)
          ],
           ),
          ),
          ));
        }


       Future<List<Map<String,dynamic>>> getJson() async {
       String apiUrl = 'http://bannermonster.com/demo.json';
       http.Response response = await http.get(apiUrl);
       return json.decode(response.body);
       }
```

Here my question is how should i pull WordPress custom post type in flutter complete slider data how to pull. I just start learning flutter can anyone point me in the right direction.this is my code here i'm not getting any errors.

Comment: Would you put a JSON example in your question?

Comment: @Yamin I added my code.

Comment: Where is it? I don't see JSON example.

Comment: @Yamin `apiurl` here I have a json WP rest API.

Comment: How can I get an example of the data? you've put only the route there, not the actual URL. update your question and put an example of WP JSON response.

Comment: @Yamin this is my json `http://bannersmonster.com/demo.json`   i want to fetch this complete json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with misspelling the URL in the code. however, the full example is here:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: MainScreen(),
  ));
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getJson(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Container(
              child: new Scaffold(
                appBar: new AppBar(
                  title: new Text('Demo'),
                  centerTitle: true,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                ),
                body: new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[new Text(snapshot.data[0]['id'].toString())],
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else if(snapshot.hasError) {
            return Container(
              child: new Scaffold(
                appBar: new AppBar(
                  title: new Text('Demo'),
                  centerTitle: true,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                ),
                body: new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[new Text(snapshot.error.toString())], //Handle error in your own way
                ),
              ),
            );
          }else{
            return Scaffold(
              body: Container(
                child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
              ),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}

Future<List<dynamic>> getJson() async {
  try {
    String apiUrl = 'http://bannersmonster.com/demo.json';
    http.Response response = await http.get(apiUrl);
    return json.decode(response.body);
  } catch (e) {
    throw Exception('Problem with data'+e.toString());
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** The above code is a simple guide for this problem. Don't use it for other porpuses.

Comment: I tried this but not getting and no errors showing. i updated my question check.

Comment: Thanks. yeah, one field is coming. but here I want to fetch complete json object.i tried like this `print(_jsonData);` but not getting.

Comment: Try print(snapshot.data.toString()); after "if (snapshot.hasData) {" . I've put one example. you should write the other parts.

Comment: Dart doesn't have undefined! put the actual error here.

Comment: Console error `Error -32601 received from application method not found` this error i'm getting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178005/discussion-between-yamin-and-husna).